# The output from my python script is NULL as soon as I make a dataframe out of a csv file

Tags: python, php, pandas

This is my first question here on stackoverflow, so please try to be forgiving of mistakes I've made or may make.

What I'm trying to do is first execute a python script using exec(), then get the output back in json format so I may use the data on my php page.

The PHP code I'm using to get this to work:

```
<?PHP 
$result = exec('python scripts/pyscript.py');
echo var_dump($result) . '<br>';
$resultData = json_decode($result);
echo var_dump($resultData);
?>
```

The python script:

```
import pandas
import sys
import json
dict1 = {1:[{'abc':1,'bcd':2}],2:[{'ddd':3,'ccc':4}]}
print(json.dumps(dict1))
```

And I'm able to get the desired data on my php page. I've verified this through the use of var_dump().

Output:

```
string(58) "{"1": [{"abc": 1, "bcd": 2}], "2": [{"ddd": 3, "ccc": 4}]}"
object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["1"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["abc"]=> int(1) ["bcd"]=> int(2) } } ["2"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["ddd"]=> int(3) ["ccc"]=> int(4) } } }
```

However, as soon as I include a line to even read a csv through pandas into a dataframe, the outputs are NULL.

```
import pandas
import json
dict2=pandas.read_csv('ce.csv');
dict1 = {1:[{'abc':1,'bcd':2}],2:[{'ddd':3,'ccc':4}]}
print(json.dumps(dict1))
```

This occurs no matter what value I try to return and the output on my php page is:

```
string(0) ""
NULL
```

**EDIT**

As asked on a comment, I have also attempted to execute the python-script by itself manually and I am able to print the dataframe.

I have also converted the dataframe into a dictionary and then printed that using print(json.dumps()), and still I get the output I desire.

Code:

```
import pandas
import json
dict2=pandas.read_csv('ce.csv');
print(dict2)
dict2=dict2.to_dict()
print(json.dumps(dict2))
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to launch the python-script manually instead of inside of php?

Comment: @HampusLarsson Yes, I have launched the python-script manually and I get the desired output from within the csv file as a dataframe. I have also tried converting the dataframe into a dictionary and used the print with json.dumps(), I still get the output. But it just doesn't work on my php page.

I will add this to my main post.

Comment: Are you sure the python script in the php environment finds the actual file ce.csv? You could try to use the glob module to check if it finds the path.

Comment: @divingTobi Yes, I am sure that the python script finds the actual file mentioned. I have verified this using the glob module. Further, I have also mentioned that I was able to achieve the output by manually executing the python script without having it output the same on the php page.